# Determining the origin of a coat of arms sketch?

Tags: france, heraldry

[image]

Here's sketch of my family's coat of arms – those are some warriors and lions and oak leaves. I read it's supposed to be the copy of some coat of arms from Notre Dame in Paris. We also got this coat of arms on our family tomb.

I'm trying to find image, origin or something about original coat of arms from Notre Dame. Any ideas?

---

I know the information I provided is weak, but this is just all I have. The picture is like official sketch of this coat of arms, since I got it from family history book, so even former researchers couldn't get any further. This book also says it was confirmed very similar coat of arms can be found in Notre Dame in Paris, but there is no further information about it. That's how I started looking for it. The one in Notre Dame has nothing to do with my family, therefore I can't provide any more information. Some ancestors had documents with original coats of arms when coming here from Belgium or France, and when they received their own arms, they simply used the one they saw there. So I'm looking for the original coat of arms and I have no idea to whom it could belong. The book only mentions those are warriors, lions and oak leaves on it, but nothing more. I started searching hoping there's any chance to get any closer to origin with only this little information or if by any chance anyone has saw or heard about it.

Thank you for your help so far, and I'm really sorry my information is so deficient, but this is all I was able to find so far.

Comment: Welcome to GFH SE!  Would you be able to edit your question (there is an edit button beneath it) to provide some more of the Genealogy and/or Family History context that lead you to ask this question here, please?  For example, what are the details of the oldest burial on the family tomb that bears this coat of arms?  Tracing back from him/her should help lead you to the source.

Comment: I've downvoted this because there isn't enough information in the question to give a meaningful response -- the name of the family concerned would be a minimum, plus the dates/places of the relevant burials.

Comment: You say " I got it from the published book".  What book?  It is always good to tell what your source is. Otherwise someone may search and post "I found another picture just like yours!" because they found it in the same book.

Answer (score 3):

Your question does not have enough information to answer it properly. Here are some things to work out to get you closer to either identifying the arms or (as I suspect) confirming that they are made up.

- the colors. It is very unusual to have a black and white arms, so presumably it is really in colors that are indicated by [hatching](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatching_system). Try to to find a better version with hatching that might suggest the colors.
- is it quarterly, or four items around a cross? Based on your drawing, I can't tell. Sam has identified it as quarterly, but I'm not so sure. The individual quarters – just a warrior and just a lion – would be very simple original arms (quartering was often a way of signifying the union of two families by marriage, and the children would quarter their arms).
- the exact position ([attitude](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_%28heraldry%29)) of the lion. It matters whether one foot is on the ground (rampant) or two (salient). I'm suspicious that the lion faces to the right (to the left from the perspective of shield bearer, so "salient sinister" in the lingo). This is unusual and makes me wonder if it is a coat of arms that the family has just adopted rather than having it officially bestowed upon them.

Once you are sure what the arms actually show and have translated it into "blazon" jargon as Sam has done, you could browse through listings such as those linked [here](http://www.heraldica.org/topics/france/). I have no idea if [this](http://worldofheraldry.info/french/french.html) is a site selling images historically legitimate arms or just made-up stuff, but it wouldn't hurt to browse through what they have to see if any of them look familiar. Obviously knowing the name if the family would help.

Of course if the arms really are from Notre Dame, they could be ecclesiastical and not actually relating to your family.

Comment: The questioner has described it as "a sketch" but could it have originally been a rubbing which has been touched up or modified?  Also, is it possible that the entire image has been reversed?  In any case, I agree that this is not a good quality question.

Comment: @JanMurphy if the picture was reversed, it would imply the warrior was left-handed, which would surprise me in a heraldic depiction.

Answer (score -1):

You could start off with sites that have coats of arms for the surname you are looking for, particularly those that focus on the nationality of your family.

These [two](https://coadb.com/) [places](http://historicresearch.com) are resources I always use. See if they work for you!